# PySpark: MutableLong cannot be cast to MutableInt

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-glue, parquet, duckdb

I am trying to read multiple parquet files from AWS Glue Job using PySpark and Glue API in the following:

```
snapshot_as_dynamic_frame = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    format_options={},
    connection_type="s3",
    format="parquet",
    connection_options={"paths": files_to_compact_s3a, "recurse": False},
    transformation_ctx="snapshot_as_dynamic_frame",
)
```

The files_*to_*compact_s3a is a list of the files names in S3 to be read. One of the files was generated by DuckDB API to create a parquet file (was run from other AWS lambda function that its purpose to compact parquet files for code optimizations):

The used DuckDB query is:

```
" COPY (" f"SELECT * FROM read_parquet({files_to_compact})) "
  f"TO '{compact_file_name}' (FORMAT 'parquet');"
```

When the AWS Glue Job try to read this parquet file (and other parquet files) it throws the following exception:

`org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.MutableLong cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.MutableIn`

This file is query able by AWS Athena and seems it does not corrupted or something else.

There is a single issue with that file which is reading it in AWS Glue PySpark Job.

I checked the file schema using another DuckDB query:

```
┌──────────────────────┬──────────────────────┬────────────┬───┬───────┬───────────┬──────────┬──────────────────────┐
│      file_name       │         name         │    type    │ … │ scale │ precision │ field_id │     logical_type     │
│       varchar        │       varchar        │  varchar   │   │ int64 │   int64   │  int64   │       varchar        │
├──────────────────────┼──────────────────────┼────────────┼───┼───────┼───────────┼──────────┼──────────────────────┤
│ s3://bmc-saas-dp-r…  │ duckdb_schema        │ NULL       │ … │  NULL │      NULL │     NULL │ NULL                 │
│ s3://bmc-saas-dp-r…  │ id                   │ BYTE_ARRAY │ … │  NULL │      NULL │     NULL │ NULL                 │
│ s3://bmc-saas-dp-r…  │ server               │ BYTE_ARRAY │ … │  NULL │      NULL │     NULL │ NULL                 │
│ s3://bmc-saas-dp-r…  │ run_id               │ BYTE_ARRAY │ … │  NULL │      NULL │     NULL │ NULL                 │
│ s3://bmc-saas-dp-r…  │ run_count            │ INT32      │ … │  NULL │      NULL │     NULL │ NULL                 │
│ s3://bmc-saas-dp-r…  │ text                 │ BYTE_ARRAY │ … │  NULL │      NULL │     NULL │ NULL                 │
│ s3://bmc-saas-dp-r…  │ text_length          │ INT64      │ … │  NULL │      NULL │     NULL │ NULL                 │
│ s3://bmc-saas-dp-r…  │ text_file_path       │ BYTE_ARRAY │ … │  NULL │      NULL │     NULL │ NULL                 │
│ s3://bmc-saas-dp-r…  │ task_type            │ BYTE_ARRAY │ … │  NULL │      NULL │     NULL │ NULL                 │
│ s3://bmc-saas-dp-r…  │ collection_time      │ INT64      │ … │  NULL │      NULL │     NULL │ TimestampType(isAd…  │
│ s3://bmc-saas-dp-r…  │ task_handle_duration │ INT64      │ … │  NULL │      NULL │     NULL │ NULL                 │
│ s3://bmc-saas-dp-r…  │ data_collector_host  │ BYTE_ARRAY │ … │  NULL │      NULL │     NULL │ NULL                 │
│ s3://bmc-saas-dp-r…  │ status_code          │ INT32      │ … │  NULL │      NULL │     NULL │ NULL                 │
│ s3://bmc-saas-dp-r…  │ failure_code         │ BYTE_ARRAY │ … │  NULL │      NULL │     NULL │ NULL                 │
│ s3://bmc-saas-dp-r…  │ failure_description  │ BYTE_ARRAY │ … │  NULL │      NULL │     NULL │ NULL                 │
│ s3://bmc-saas-dp-r…  │ version              │ BYTE_ARRAY │ … │  NULL │      NULL │     NULL │ NULL                 │
│ s3://bmc-saas-dp-r…  │ rule                 │ BYTE_ARRAY │ … │  NULL │      NULL │     NULL │ NULL                 │
│ s3://bmc-saas-dp-r…  │ dynamic_partition_…  │ INT64      │ … │  NULL │      NULL │     NULL │ NULL                 │
│ s3://bmc-saas-dp-r…  │ day                  │ INT64      │ … │  NULL │      NULL │     NULL │ NULL                 │
│ s3://bmc-saas-dp-r…  │ month                │ INT64      │ … │  NULL │      NULL │     NULL │ NULL                 │
│ s3://bmc-saas-dp-r…  │ rule_name            │ BYTE_ARRAY │ … │  NULL │      NULL │     NULL │ NULL                 │
│ s3://bmc-saas-dp-r…  │ year                 │ INT64      │ … │  NULL │      NULL │     NULL │ NULL                 │
├──────────────────────┴──────────────────────┴────────────┴───┴───────┴───────────┴──────────┴──────────────────────┤
│ 22 rows                                                                                       11 columns (7 shown) │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

I suspect about the timestamp type of the column 'collection_time' but I am not sure which column produces the problem.

I tried to set spark session properties in the glue job like:

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.parquet.mergeSchema", "true")
```

But nothing helped.

I will appreciate a lot if a solution will be provided.

Thanks.